# Kotlin Wildcard Capture on List Callback Parameter

Tags: kotlin

Java:

```
public class JavaClass implements ModelController.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onModelsLoaded(@NonNull List<? extends Model> models) {
        doSomething(models);
    }

    private void doSomething(List<Model> models) { }

}
```

Kotlin:

```
class ModelController {
    var callback = WeakReference<Callback>(null)

    interface Callback {
        fun onModelsLoaded(models: List<Model>)
    }

    fun someFunction() {
        callback.get().onModelsLoaded(ArrayList<Model>())
    }
}

interface Model {

}
```

Without the ? extends Model in the Java onModelsLoaded method, the override doesn’t match the interface made in Kotlin. With it, I get the following error:

```
doSomething(<java.util.List<com.yada.Model>) cannot be applied to (java.util.List<capture<? extends com.yada.Model>>)
```

Why is the wildcard capture required and why doesn't it allow it to be used against the non-wildcard method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue stems from Kotlin collections being [variant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), and Java only having use-site variance which is implemented though wildcards (capture is something connected to wildcards but not exactly the `? extends ...` syntax itself).

When in Kotlin we say `List<Model>` it means "read-only list of `Model` or subtypes of `Model`", when we say the same in Java it means "mutable list of exactly `Model` and nothing else". To mean roughly what Kotlin's `List<Model>` means, in Java we have to say `List<? extends Model>`, this is why for the override to work you have to add the wildcard into the Java code.

Now, your `doSomething` is written in Java and says that it wants "a list of exactly `Model`", and when you are giving it "a list of `Model` or its subtypes", the Java compiler complains, because it can be dangerous: `doSomething` might try to do something that is not legitimate for a list of, say, `ModelImpl`, because it thinks it's working on a list of `Model`.

As of now (Kotlin Beat 2), you have two options:

- use `MutableList<Model>` in your Kotlin code - this mean exactly what Java's `List<Model>` means, or
- define `doSomething` so that it takes `List<? extends Model>`, which is what your current Kotlin code means.

In the next update of Kotlin we'll add an annotation on types to facilitate a somewhat cleaner workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with capture<? extends Model>

You may do something like this:

```
void doSomething(List<Model> models) {
    new ArrayList(models)
}
```